# Push notifications capability no selector in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I am try to learn about push notifications on iOS. For that I am reading the Raywenderlich book.

On the other hand I have realised that, on Xcode 11, some rearrangements/changes have been done when configuring xcodeproj and one of them is the Capabilities and the selector for enabling Push notifications.

[image]

At this point i am not sure if it is on or off.

That's the content of entitlements file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Which at least shows it is configured

In my AppDelegate I have the following code:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert]) { granted, _ in
        guard granted else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }

    }

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let token = deviceToken.reduce("") { $0 + String(format: "%02x", $1) }
    print(token)

}
```

When the app starts, push notifications permissions are requested but `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is never called.

So, I know in previous versions of Xcode there is a On/Off selector so:

- Is it on or off?
- Is the fact that didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken never gets called related?

**EDIT**

- On a real device.
- Letting Xcode to deal with all the signing.

Comment: are you trying it on a real device? push doesn't work on simulators, also i think you need to select the project, not a particular scheme

Comment: Did you enable it for your app id in developer account?

Comment: Yes. I forgot to mention that ...

Comment: @TheTiger Letting Xcode to deal with the signing

Comment: clean the code. check auto signing option will help you.

Comment: Yes that worked. How about on/off? is in Xcode 11 always on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Just add it only, by adding it means that you accept that your app receive notifications.

check here also

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_capabilities_to_your_app